# Extract specific value from text on shell script

Tags: regex, shell, awk, cut

I am reading a text file to extract some specific information. I was able to solve it using a simple pipeline like:

```
line='[any] a b "c a" valuewanted k o'
echo $line | cut -d " " -f 6 | sort -u
# prints valuewanted
```

But I was checking all log text and I see values with another spaces that are breaking my pipeline. As example:

```
line='[any] a "b 1" "c a" valuewanted k o'
echo $line | cut -d " " -f 6 | sort -u

#prints a"
# must change -f to -f 7
```

Also I have tried using `aws '{print $6}'` but happens same error.

I am reading a big file so it's unviable changing position for every single line. Each line has a pattern where each group it's splited by a space. If the content is between double quotes, it's related to same group not different groups like I am parsing in my script.

When a group has some space, entire group value is around double quotes.

Is there anyway to make command `cut` split by spaces and handle `"content whatever"` as a single group?

Comment: Not the problem you're asking about but use `echo "$line"`, not `echo $line` - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Run all your code through http://shellcheck.net til you get more familiar with shell scripts (I frequently do it today after 40 years writing shell scripts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [gnu-awk with `FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/More-CSV.html):

```bash
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^[:blank:]]+' -v OFS='|' '
{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' file

[any]|a|b|"c a"|valuewanted|k|o
[any]|a|"b 1"|"c a"|valuewanted|k|o

# input data
cat file

[any] a b "c a" valuewanted k o
[any] a "b 1" "c a" valuewanted k o
```

I used `print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7` to demonstrate all field values. You can change it to whatever you like.

You can use `b` and `"b 1"` in 3rd field in both lines.

Note that `"[^"]*"|[^[:blank:]]+` is a regex pattern that uses alternation to match a double quoted string or else matches1+ characters of non-whitespace characters as a field.